# How can I make my Neural Network predict new output values?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm working on a project where I have 3 inputs `(v, f, n)` and 1 output `(delta(t))`.
I'm trying to test the effect of the inputs on the output and to figure out which input is the most effective in different situations, therefore I would like to predict **new output values** that depend on new inputs values.

I have been testing this system and I got the following data table:

[image]

This table contains 1000 rows.

I'm new to this whole Neural Network thing, so I don't know what should be the Activation function, the loss function, etc.
I've been trying use some Keras models, but I'm getting wrong predictions when trying `model.predict()` some inputs values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mse')

data = np.array(pd.read_excel(r'Data.xlsx'))

x = data[:, :3]
y = data[:, 3]

target = model.fit(x, y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=15000, 
batch_size=256)

# check some predictions:
print(model.predict([[0.9, 840370875, 240]]))
```

Comment: clarify about the type of features, is it available to take the feature `f` as categorical feature or not?

Comment: I agree with @Soroush Mirzaei, can f be consider categorical? Beside of that at least from snipet you not norm your inputs.

Comment: f is a quantitative variable, so it can't be consider categorical.
I'll try norm my data. Anyway, how can I know what Activation function to choose? 
I mean, is the Relu model fit to this situation?
In addition, which mode should I use (FCN, CNN, LSTM, etc)?

Comment: It seems there are outliers in your data. You can use `tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError` loss function and normalize your data to fix that issue as well as you can try by increasing the Dense units values in the model definition. Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) link as a reference formore details.